# Infinite while loop assistance

Tags: java, networking

I am learning Network Programming in Java Core. Here is something I can't understand. Take a look at this snippet

[image]

This loop seems infinite. But I sure know it could stop (not by exiting the program)

My question is which situations this loop would stop in the case of no existing program. I doubt there would be a statement in this loop body that raises an exception or somehow one of the statements inside the loop body generates a BREAK statement. How can i get this while loop to exit?

Comment: what do you want the stop condition to be?

Comment: Don't post text/code as image: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1393766

Comment: What do you mean, "I sure know it could stop?"  The loop in your example will _never_ stop unless one of those method calls throws an exception, or the process is killed by some other process.

Comment: If you are asking how to _make_ it stop, then it would help if we knew the circumstances under which you _want_ it to stop.  Why would you want it to stop?  Looks like maybe, if the client disconnects, that might be one good reason.  What does `inputFromClient.readDouble()` do if the client has disconnected?  If it throws an exception, then maybe what you want is to write a handler for that exception outside the loop.

Comment: @jameslarge U hit that, thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a breaking condition in loop expression

```
while(true) // is an end less loop unless you have break inside it.
```

What you can do is

```
while(true) {

    break; 
     // it will exit the loop when it hits that statement. 
     // break can be used inside an if too.
}
```

Typically you should fix your `while(true)` to `while(condition_which_will_break_this_loop)`. Start reading  [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_loop_control.htm) to give you a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

you should have an explicit break condition. another way the loop might stop is if any of the method calls

```
outputToClient.writeDouble(area);

jta.append(...)
jta.append(...)
```

throws an exception

Answer (score -1):

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) is some documentation to how loops in java work. On the line :

```
while(true)
```

This condition is never equal to false.

> The while statement evaluates expression, which must return a boolean value. If the expression evaluates to true, the while statement executes the statement(s) in the while block. The while statement continues testing the expression and executing its block until the expression evaluates to false.

so your loop never terminates. You can either change this condition like so

```
boolean done = false;
while(!done){
    if(condition is met)
        done = true;
}
```

Another way to do this is add a break statement inside of your loop, although its practice tends to be more frowned upon as apposed to a conditional termination it still works.

```
while(true){
    if(condition is met)
        break;
}
```